# How do I stop my python code from printing none after it prints the string?

Tags: python

```py
str = input("Please enter y to start the program: ")
while str == 'y':
    def printNTimes(s, n):
        for i in range(n):
            print(s)

    phrase = input("Enter a string: ")
    number = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))

    allTogether = printNTimes(phrase, number)

    print(allTogether)
    print()    
    str = input("Please enter y if you want to continue: ")
print("DONE")
```

Output:

```
Please enter y to start the program: y
Enter a string: Hi
Enter a positive number: 3
Hi
Hi
Hi
None

Please enter y if you want to continue:
```

Comment: `printNTimes` already does the printing and doesn't return anything, which means it will return `None`. You assign that result to `allTogether` and then proceed to print `allTogether`, which prints `None`. Just call `printNTimes` and don't assign the result to a variable and don't print it.

Comment: @Grismar, `printNTimes` is inside the while loop.

Comment: It is now, but it wasn't when I wrote the comment.

Comment: Why the function printNTimes when you can do simple like this -> print(phrase*number)

Comment: Another thing is the function printNTimes doesn't return any value but you are trying to print a value from it. So None is returned

Comment: @Ruthvik This is for an assignment. I have to use a function that accepts user inputs for the string and the integer.

Comment: @Brain Correa, So the simplest solution is to remove this line -> print(allTogether)

Comment: Beside the point, but `str` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `str` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). Use a more descriptive name, or at least something like `s`. For an example problem this could cause, see [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](/q/31087111/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea Ah ok, I'll fix the variable name as well. I got my program to work now. I appreciate the input from everyone! This is my first semester learning Python so I'm trying to better my programming etiquette.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `print(allTogether)`, or the variable itself, because when you print it, you get an extra `None` (because the function returns `None` i.e, it does not return anything).

Also, put the function outside the while loop so that it is easier to read.

```
def printNTimes(s, n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(s)

str = input("Please enter y to start the program: ")
while str == 'y':
    phrase = input("Enter a string: ")
    number = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))

    printNTimes(phrase, number)
    print()    
    str = input("Please enter y if you want to continue: ")
print("DONE")
```

Just call the function. You could use `return` and then `print` the function, but this might be easier.

Comment: Okay, this helped a lot. Thank you for the feedback plus the tip on putting the function outside the while loop. I'm in an introduction to Python class, so I'm still learning proper programming etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function printNtime is actually being used as a subroutine, meaning it doesn't RETURN any values.

I am not sure what you want as a final output so here's two solution.
IF USED AS SUBROUTINE: just remove the `print(allTogether)`
IF USED AS A FUNCTION: you need to create a string variable in the function and return it.

```
def printNTimes(s, n):
  mystring = ""
  for i in range(n):
    mystring = mystring + s + "\n"
  return mystring
```

Comment: Presumably, a function called "printNTimes" is going to do the printing for you, so the subroutine option makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is because your routine, `printNTimes()`, returns a None value. You say:

```
allTogether = printNTimes(phrase, number)

print(allTogether)
```

`allTogether` is set to None because printNTimes does not return a value. When you call `print(allTogether)`, that's what is printing the None.

It sounds like you intended your `printNTimes()` routine to assemble one big string of all the output and return it, which you would then print out via the `print(allTogether)` call. But your `printNTimes()` routine is calling the print() method and outputing the text then. So, you need to rewrite your `printNTimes()` method.  Also, note that defining that function inside the loop is not necessary. Once is sufficient. So something like this should suffice:

```
def printNTimes(s, n):
    s_out = ""
    for i in range(n):
        s_out += s + '\n'
    return s_out
str_ = input("Please enter y to start the program: ")
while str_ == 'y':

    phrase = input("Enter a string: ")
    number = int(input("Enter a positive number: "))

    allTogether = printNTimes(phrase, number)

    print(allTogether)
    print()    
    str_ = input("Please enter y if you want to continue: ")
print("DONE")
```

Also note that I renamed your `str` variable to `str_`. `str` is a Python type, a reserved word that should not be reused.